# how to use the same drop down list in different web pages

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following drop down list and I would like to use it in several pages

```
<form action = "Unser Team.php" method = "post" name = "test">
    <div class = "custom-select">
    <div class = "select">
        <select id ="custom-select" name = "custom-select" style="width:200px;" onchange = " this.form.submit();">
            <option <?php if ($_POST['custom-select'] == 'Abteilung auswählen') print 'selected '; ?>value="Abteilung auswählen">Abteilung auswählen</option>
            <option <?php if ($_POST['custom-select'] == 'TL-311') print 'selected '; ?> value="TL-311">TL-311</option>
            <option <?php if ($_POST['custom-select'] == 'TP-271') print 'selected '; ?> value="TP-271">TP-271</option>
            <option <?php if ($_POST['custom-select'] == 'TP-310') print 'selected '; ?> value="TP-310">TP-310</option>
            <option <?php if ($_POST['custom-select'] == 'TP-270') print 'selected '; ?> value="TP-270">TP-270</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

when the user selects an option I save it and I would like to see in the next page the option that has been selected is preselected and for its use the following code
in the home page:

```
var file;

function myFunction()
{
    var mylist = document.getElementById("custom-select");
    var mytext = mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].text;
    window.file = mytext;
    return window.file;
}

window.onload = function() {
    var getInput = window.file;
    localStorage.setItem("files",getInput);
}
```

for the other pages:

```
var myFile = localStorage.getItem("files");

window.onload = function() {
    var ddValue= localStorage.getItem('files');
    var dd= document.getElementById('custom-select');
    for(var i = 0;i < dd.options.length;i++){
        if(dd.options[i].value == ddValue ){
            dd.options[i].selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

with this the selected value in the home page is preselected in the next pages but the problem is that with this code I can not change the selected value i the drop down list in other pages. can please somebody help me?
I am new in web programming.

Comment: I don’t see `myFunction` getting called anywhere?

Comment: Why are you trying to store this info on the client side in the first place? This is using PHP already, so why not put it into the PHP session?

Comment: first of all thank you verry much for giving me a answer so fast. Indeed I am new in web programming as I mentioned above and this is the first time I use PHP and I'm still learning that's why I did not know this method. Can you please tell me more about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, welcome to Stackoverflow!

As pointed out by **misorude**, it might be wise to utilize the PHP session. When you switch from one page to another, without a form's submit, you will lose the `$_POST` variable. Which I believe is your problem here?

What happens when you you use sessions however, is that the client saves an ID as cookie. Every time it communicates with your server, it supplies this "session_id". This way the server will be able to grab the right session variables for that client.

Using sessions is fairly easy, call `session_start();` at the top of your script. From there on you can use `$_SESSION["var_name"] = "value";`

For more details on the topic, you might want to read [this article on w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

Comment: Thank you very much i will try this method. in fact I was not yet aware of this method. it's my first time to do web programming. Thanks